# Databinding Progress Bar Not Binding

Tags: wpf, binding, progress-bar

I searched a lot for the solution to this, but can't seem to figure it out. (Just saying, this will be a long post)

Preface: This is NOT MVVM

Problem: I have a progress bar. I am currently trying to bind a public double to it from within the xaml's .cs file. However, whenever I use value's bind function, it never works, resulting in iNotifyPropertyChanged not working, etc. etc....

The variable it is bound to serves the purpose of updating the progress bar value. The way that is completed is by setting the value in a separate for loop in another method/class. The value is set by a simple equation. 100 divided by the length of a list, multiplied by the for loops counter. This gives us a real number that can be put into the progress bar value. (code below)

```
    Binder.daWindow.progUpdate = ((100.00 / databaseTables.Length) * dbTIndex);
```

I know this can be completed by threading (or whatever), but I would appreciate answers specifically for how this might be done by binding (unless it's impossible, then forget what I just said).

XAML:

```
<Window x:Name="DateWindow1" x:Class="WpfApp1.DateWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
    xmlns:Main="using:DateWindow"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Change Dates" Height="232.667" Width="462" Background="#FF2B2B2B" ResizeMode="NoResize">



    <Grid>
    <TextBox x:Name="DayChangeTextBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" Margin="176,45,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="##" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="58" FontSize="14" TextAlignment="Center" AcceptsReturn="False" AcceptsTab="False" GotFocus="DayChangeTextBox_GotFocus" LostFocus="DayChangeTextBox_LostFocus" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" OpacityMask="Black" Background="#FFFDFDFD"/>
    <Label Content="Days" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="239,45,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="42" FontSize="14" FontFamily="Microsoft YaHei UI" Height="30" Foreground="White"/>
    <Label Content="Move Dates Forward:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="23,45,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="144" FontSize="14" FontFamily="Microsoft JhengHei UI Light" Height="30" Foreground="White"/>
    <Button x:Name="ChangeDatesButton" Content="Change Dates" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="303,45,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="143" Height="30" BorderThickness="1,1,2,3" BorderBrush="#FF474747" Click="ChangeDatesButton_Click" FontFamily="Microsoft YaHei UI" Background="#FFE6E6E6"/>
    <Label x:Name="serverLabel" Content="Label" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,73,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Width="5" Height="15" Visibility="Hidden"/>
    <Label x:Name="databaseLabel" Content="Label" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="20,73,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="3" Visibility="Hidden" Height="15"/>
    <Button x:Name="RevertToDefaultButton" Content="Revert to Backup" Margin="23,164,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="30" Background="#FFE6E6E6" BorderBrush="#FF474747" BorderThickness="1,1,2,3" Click="RevertToDefaultButton_Click" FontFamily="Microsoft JhengHei UI" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="143"/>
    <Button x:Name="OverwriteDefaultButton" Content="Backup Database" Margin="23,128,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="30" BorderBrush="#FF474747" BorderThickness="1,1,2,3" Click="OverwriteDefaultButton_Click" FontFamily="Microsoft JhengHei UI" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="143" Background="#FFE6E6E6" />
    <Button x:Name="CloseButton" Content="Close" Margin="0,164,10,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="30" BorderBrush="#FF474747" BorderThickness="1,1,2,3" FontFamily="Microsoft JhengHei UI" Width="60" Click="CloseButton_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Background="#FFE6E6E6" />
    <Label x:Name="RevertBackupLabel" Content="Backup or Revert Database:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,93,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="White" FontFamily="Microsoft JhengHei UI" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="16"/>
    <Label x:Name="DatesLabel" Content="Change Dates in Database:" Margin="12,10,0,0" Foreground="White" FontFamily="Microsoft JhengHei UI" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="216" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <ProgressBar HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="13" Margin="303,80,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="143" Name="pbStatus"  Value="{Binding local.progUpdate, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Maximum="{Binding mx}" Minimum="{Binding mn}" LargeChange="0.01"/>
</Grid>
```

XAML CS Portion:

```
public static class Binder
{
    public static DateWindow daWindow;
}
public partial class DateWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private double _progUpdate;
    public double progUpdate
    {
        get { return _progUpdate; }
        set
        {
            _progUpdate = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(progUpdate)));
            }

        }

    }
    public double mx = 100;
    public double mn = 0; 


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public DateWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Binder.daWindow = this; 
        ChangeDateInDatabase ChangeDate = new ChangeDateInDatabase();
        progUpdate = 25; // This is there so we can test the variable without going through the whole program. 
    }

    private void ChangeDatesButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ChangeDateInDatabase ChangeDate = new ChangeDateInDatabase();
        var result = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you would like to change dates for  " + Globals.selectedDatabase + " from server " + Globals.main.ServerComboBox.Text + "?", "Change Dates?", MessageBoxButton.YesNo, MessageBoxImage.Exclamation);
        if (Globals.main.ServerComboBox.Text != "" && Globals.selectedDatabase != "" && FindDatabaseAndServer.Connector(Globals.main.ServerComboBox.Text, Globals.selectedDatabase) && result == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
        {
            try
            {
                long.Parse(DayChangeTextBox.Text);
                ChangeDate.ChangeDates(this); 
                //ChangeDateInDatabase.ChangeDates(this);

            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show($"Invalid number {DayChangeTextBox.Text}, please enter a valid number.", "ERROR", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
            }
        }
    }
```

(CLICK function serves the purpose of calling a method for the program. Inside the method, its main loop, which determines the methods completion, contains the  variable desired to be bound with a defining equation for its value)

Method Containing Said Loop:

```
for (int dbTIndex = 0; dbTIndex < databaseTables.Length; dbTIndex++)
                    {
                        string[] dateColumns = new string[0];
                        string columnSelectQuery = "SELECT DATA_TYPE, COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS  WHERE TABLE_NAME = '" + databaseTables[dbTIndex].ToString() + "' AND COLUMN_NAME LIKE '_%'";
                        using (SqlConnection connection2 = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                        {
                            SqlCommand command2 = new SqlCommand(columnSelectQuery, connection2);
                            connection2.Open();
                            SqlDataReader reader2 = command2.ExecuteReader();
                                int y = 0;
                                while (reader2.Read())
                                {
                                    if (reader2[0].ToString() == "datetime")
                                    {
                                        Array.Resize(ref dateColumns, dateColumns.Length + 1);
                                        dateColumns[y] = reader2[1].ToString();
                                        y++;
                                    }
                                }
                        }
                        for (var dtColIndex = 0; dtColIndex < dateColumns.Length; dtColIndex++)
                        {
                            string addDatesQuery = "UPDATE " + databaseTables[dbTIndex] + " SET " + dateColumns[dtColIndex] + " = DATEADD(dd," + Convert.ToInt32(date.DayChangeTextBox.Text) + "," + dateColumns[dtColIndex] + ") WHERE " + dateColumns[dtColIndex] + " IS NOT NULL";

                            using (SqlConnection connection3 = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                            {
                                    SqlCommand command3 = new SqlCommand(addDatesQuery, connection3);
                                    connection3.Open();
                                    command3.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            }
                        }
                        //vvvvv VARIABLE THAT NEEDS TO BE BOUND vvvvvvv
                        Binder.daWindow.progUpdate = ((100.00 / databaseTables.Length) * dbTIndex);
                    }
```

(There is obviously more code to this part, which I can provide if needed)

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

For the XAML, local.progUpdate is not the only thing I have tried. I've done path, progUpdate by itself, etc.

Comment: USER SOLUTION: 

The code's issue is caused by misusing threads. Don't do what I did, trying to fix this problem without understanding what the problem is. Get a basic understanding of how threads work. 

I believe there were 2 possible problems (besides the binding). First is that working thread was being overloaded, causing the UI not to change till the end. The second possibility was that the UI was being called on a thread that was not understood by the UI. Maybe a mixture?

Using a background worker & (current) dispatcher in the looping method corrected the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your ProgressBar's first binding makes no sense: `{Binding local.progUpdate, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}`. You're not specifying a source, and there's no `DataContext` assigned anywhere, so the binding won't evaluate to anything because the path is meaningless. Because the property is on the window itself, you can just assign the window's data context to itself.

```
// DateWindow.xaml.cs
public DateWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = this;
    ...
}

<!-- DateWindow.xaml -->
<ProgressBar Value="{Binding progUpdate, Mode=OneWay}" ... />
```

Your other bindings will require `mx` and `mn` to be properties rather than fields.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I see where I wasn't making sense (new to wpf). I have it updating within the xaml's cs, but it does not update in the second method until the method is done. Any idea on how to fix that?

Comment: @user9622460 Just from eyeballing it, I'd say it's probably because you're doing non-trivial work repeatedly on the UI thread. All of the `PropertyChanged` events are firing, but there's not enough time to update the view. This is usually solved by putting the heavy lifting on another thread, but you have to be sure to update the UI property `progUpdate` on the UI thread or else the PropertyChanged event won't be caught. Your current setup is a mess, so it'll be difficult to separate the concerns.

Comment: any good ideas on how to put the UI refreshing in a different thread?

Comment: I'll start off by saying that updating the UI from a different thread is a symptom of bad design. There's a way to do it, but it's just going to make your code even less manageable. With the disclaimer out of the way, take a look at `Dispatcher.Invoke` (or the asynchronous version, `BeginInvoke`). The easiest dispatcher to access on a different thread is `System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher`

Comment: Okay! What would be your suggestion on making the code work in a more manageable way?

Comment: `IProgress<T>` (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2012/06/06/async-in-4-5-enabling-progress-and-cancellation-in-async-apis/) looks like it would be extremely helpful in your app. In fact I think you could adopt this without many fundamental changes.

Comment: thanks for the help! Bout a month into WPF (and pretty new to coding in general!), so I really hadn't even considered the thought of threads conflicting.

My solution (though it probably can be improved upon greatly), was by pretty much redoing a lot of the code. Mainly, by implementing a Background worker. 

Using the background worker calls the wanted method on its on thread, so that fixed the issue of overloading a single thread (which made the UI not update). 

Using the background worker & a dispatcher, which called upon the UI's thread,  the bar is able to update!

Comment: Get familiar with the await/async pattern and the Task class, it will go a long way in avoiding these kinds of issues and are kind of a must once you start doing complex WPF and want a usable interface.